Different meanings of would

He promised he would be taking care of the kid

As a child, If/when she came we would play games together


1 is future in the past. Original words were said in the future tense "I will be taking care of the kid" and became shifted to the past.
Is 2 too future in the past? I am not sure. Maybe it is just an equivalent to "used to" and there is no future in the past?

You're right; this is one of the ways we can talk about "habitual past actions."

This question is similar to: Use of would in sentences. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AndyBonner so my 2 example with if/when referes to habitual actions like "used to" there is no future in the past, right?

"Future in the past" is really one way of saying "two different points in the past." "As a child" is not a clear point, certainly not one that comes before playing games. No, there is no "timeline" here.

@AndyBonner let's get rid of "as a child" let's leave "when she came we would play games together". Do you consider it now future in the past or just would thete is the same as used to?

Comments are not meant for long chat or for changing the question, but: Meaning comes mostly from context. It seems almost as if you're trying to create a version of the sentence that doesn't refer to habitual past actions but rather to past plans. Doing that would take more than one sentence; surrounding sentences would have to explain the idea (and it still might not be the best approach for this particular sentence).

I haven't answered this question because I feel like the best solution for you is to read the page I linked to, and maybe others that you find by googling "would for habitual past actions," and then opening new questions about whatever isn't clear to you after a bit of reading (or maybe editing this one).

Let's not recall Mandy Rice-Davies!

I don't think the referenced 'duplicate' question/answer is helpful at all. If anything, the linked question should have been voted closed on the grounds of being tantamount to proofreading. There is no question about tenses, just "what do these mean". So I'm happy to answer this here.

@MichaelHarvey, I'm impressed with your memory! I had to google the name, and guess what? There's even a Wiki article on that reply.

Thomas - I think you mean "When I was a child" anyway (though presumably she was one as well).

@PeterKirkpatrick - the Profumo affair was a hot topic the year I was 11.

"Would" is used in very different ways, depending on the tense. It must be difficult for an English learner.

It can be the past tense of 'will', and refer to what happened multiple times in the past, what always happened, or what typically happened. This is the case with your example "as a child, we would play games together". The childhood is in the past, so was the playing of games together.

It can be used to say to refer to a hypothetical future, if a condition was met. For example "if I won the lottery, I would buy a Ferrari".

It can be used to speak what should have happened, or what was stated/expected to happen in the future, from the perspective of the past. This is the case with your example "he promised he would be taking care of the kid". The event that happened in the past was the promise, and the action of taking care of the kid is either something that is yet to happen, is expected to be happening now, or was expected to have happened (whether it did or not may be yet unknown).



in the present I could say " when/ if you come we will be playing games together" and it might mean two thing one I already start playing before or it is my plan to play with you after you arrive. Are both meanins possible with my past version of that sentence?
